# Android Multiple AsyncTasks from a listview row click

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an issue with with multiple clicks on a ListView using custom adapter.

I'm catching the onClick events all fine, the problem is that I need to start an AsyncTask on each row click that calls a webservice.
Its the same AsyncTask, just with different params.

If the user clicks on multiple rows fast, only the last AsyncTask is fired and that row is only updated.

Code to handle onClick()

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            Item item = (Item) mylLstView.getAdapter().getItem(position);           


            //execute AsyncTask
        }
    });
```

My AsyncTask

```
private class CheckItemInOrOutTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Boolean>
{
    private int position;
    Item singleItem;

    public CheckItemInOrOutTask(int position, Item singleItem)
    {
        this.position = position;
        this.singleItem = singleItem;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();           
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) 
    {
        try 
        {
            HttpClient client = HttpUtil.getHttpClient();
            String reqString = "Items?action=checkin";

            HttpPost post = HttpUtil.makePost(reqString);       

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("item_id", singleItem.getId()));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type_id", singleItem.getTypeId()));              

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));               

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode == 200) 
            {           
                String result = HttpUtil.responseToString(response);    
                JSONObject jsonItem = new JSONObject(result);
                Item item = new Item(); 

                // parse json
                // set item properties          

                itemList.set(position,item);                    
            }               
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }   

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);    

        //if (result) 
        {
            updateAdapter();                            
        }       
    }       
}
```

Can someone shed some light on it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using ProgressDialog for this updating ?? and you want to update all the rows which user clicked ??

Comment: I'm not using a ProgressDialog.
The app is expected to be used in this way, that a user can click on rows one after each other fast.
And then update all of the rows.

Comment: What's in `updateAdapter()`?

Comment: This `itemList.set(position,item);  ` also looks fishy. Your AsyncTask should return an Item instead of the Boolean, and anything that updates the adapter should go in the onPostExecute, but that's just for correctness, it might not affect the actual outcome.

Comment: For that you can use Select-able options right ??? Means check box some thing like that.. so first need to get the positions which user want to update.. then update those rows..

Comment: updateAdapter only has

itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Else get all the positions which user clicking.. at last start the asynctask with the positions.. user clicked. that time make run the async task multiple times.. on post execute call it again and again.. that time use progress dialog..

Comment: I can't have a multiple select or an extra button after the user has clicked on all the rows needed to update.
It needs to be on the fly.

Comment: Have you read the "*Order of execution*" section of the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) Maybe your tasks are just queued up and it takes time.

Comment: Unfortunately they aren't coming in later. I've waited really long.

Can I use Runnable to call the webservice and then update the ui when done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out it wasn't the AsyncTask that was the culprit.
It was because I was reusing my HttpClient.